# Chrome OS Version 105 cannot eject CD on old MacBook Pro

Tags: compact-disc, google-chrome-os

I have an old MacBook Pro (2013 model), a supported laptop of Chrome OS, installed with Chrome OS Version 105.0.5195.112. I inserted a CD-ROM into the laptop, but the Files app in the Chrome OS does not recognize the CD-ROM.

I tried to eject the disc via the Eject button, but there is no response at all. Am I suppose to understand that the Eject button is not supported in Chrome OS?

My question is: How can I eject the disc?

---

**UPDATE**

Here is the output of `ls -al /dev`:

```
$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 13 root   root         700 Sep 15 20:50 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         154 Jun 10 15:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root          60 Sep 15 20:50 bus
crw--w----  1 root   tty     136,   0 Sep 15 20:51 console
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup       36 Sep 15 20:50 .container_token
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          11 Sep 15 20:50 core -> /proc/kcore
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup        3 Sep 15 20:49 .cros_milestone
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root          80 Sep 15 20:50 dri
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          13 Sep 15 20:50 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw-  1 nobody nogroup   1,   7 Sep 15 20:49 full
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   root     10, 229 Sep 15 20:50 fuse
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup       13 Sep 15 20:49 .host_ip
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          12 Sep 15 20:50 initctl -> /run/initctl
crw-rw----  1 root   kvm      10, 232 Sep 15 20:50 kvm
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          28 Sep 15 20:50 log -> /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root          80 Sep 15 20:50 .lxc
-r--r--r--  1 root   root          37 Sep 15 20:50 .lxc-boot-id
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody nogroup       60 Sep 15 20:49 lxd
drwx--x--x  2 nobody nogroup       40 Sep 15 20:50 .lxd-mounts
drwxrwxrwt  2 nobody nogroup       40 Sep 15 20:50 mqueue
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root          60 Sep 15 20:50 net
crw-rw-rw-  1 nobody nogroup   1,   3 Sep 15 20:49 null
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   root      5,   2 Sep 15 20:51 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root           0 Sep 15 20:50 pts
crw-rw-rw-  1 nobody nogroup   1,   8 Sep 15 20:49 random
drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root          40 Sep 15 20:50 shm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root         140 Sep 15 20:50 snd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root         100 Sep 15 20:50 .ssh
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          15 Sep 15 20:50 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          15 Sep 15 20:50 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          15 Sep 15 20:50 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rw-  1 nobody nogroup   5,   0 Sep 15 20:49 tty
crw-rw-rw-  1 nobody nogroup   1,   9 Sep 15 20:49 urandom
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   root    245,   0 Sep 15 20:50 wl0
crw-rw-rw-  1 nobody nogroup   1,   5 Sep 15 20:49 zero
```

and this is the output of `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda   254:0    0 54.4M  1 disk /opt/google/cros-containers
vdb   254:16   0   10G  0 disk /dev/net/tun
pmem0 259:0    0  418M  0 disk /dev/.ssh/sshd_config
```

I think the Linux commands won't work, as in Chrome OS, the Linux is in fact a virtual machine, instead of controlling the Chrome OS itself.

Comment: Have you tried `eject `cdrom/devname`? where `devname` is something like cdrom0

Comment: I didn't enable Linux functions. Let me try later.

Comment: Checked. There is no `dev` like `cdrom`

Comment: It does not appear that ChromeOS has not been configured to detect the device. You will have to use a paper clip to eject the cd from the device and then resolve the fact Chrome OS does not detect it.  How you do that is beyond the limitations of my knowledge at this moment.

Comment: @William not quite true, Chrome OS can read CD ROM since at least 3 years ago: https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/dt895v/chromeos_can_read_cd_now/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Chrome OS is unable to detect the CD-ROM hardware of my MacBook, the only way to eject the CD-ROM from the laptop is to prepare a USB macOS install media (in my case I use macOS Catalina USB Install drive), then launch the install sequence of macOS by holding Option key during bootup and select USB to boot.

Then, in the macOS Installation "wizard", select Disk Utility, I can see my CD-ROM, and I can finally click Eject. Last, cancel the Installation process, and reboot back to Chrome OS.

I promise I won't insert a CD-ROM into the device anymore. Quite troublesome to eject a disc. I hope the Chrome OS can eventually identify the disc drive of the old MacBook, as the MacBook Pro is claimed to be "supported".

Comment: Don't MacBooks have an eject pinhole?

Comment: No, it doesn't have one.